# Line integral in cylindrical coordinates? Confused over notation

Tags: electromagnetism, coordinate-systems, notation, integration

In multivariable calculus the line integrals was parameterized and denoted:
\begin{gather*}
\int_l \mathbf{A} \cdot \, d\mathbf{r}  = \int_\gamma \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{r}(t)) \cdot \, \frac{d\mathbf{r}(t)}{dt}dt \tag{1}\\
\text{where} \quad \mathbf{r}(t)=x(t)\mathbf{\hat i}+y(t)\mathbf{\hat j}+z(t)\mathbf{\hat k} 
\end{gather*} 
 However in electromagnetism the line integrals are confusing.

Exemple: Suppose a charge is moving from point $b(\rho_b,\phi_b,z_b)$ to point $a(\rho_a,\phi_a,z_a)$ along the direction of $\rho$ (cylindrical coordinates):
\begin{gather*}
-\int_b^a \frac{Q\phi_L}{2\pi\epsilon_0 \rho}\mathbf{\hat \rho} \cdot (\mathbf{\hat \rho}\, d\rho+\mathbf{\hat \phi} \, \rho d\phi + \hat z \, dz)=\\
=-\int_b^a \frac{Q\phi_L}{2\pi\epsilon_0 \rho}\mathbf{\hat \rho} \cdot \mathbf{\hat \rho}  \, d\rho = -\int_b^a \frac{Q\phi_L}{2\pi\epsilon_0 \rho} \, d\rho 
\end{gather*}
This notation confuses me.
In math the procedure was; parametrize the curve, take the derivative of it, dot it with the parameterized field, as in (1). How can I use this approach in the exemple?

**How can I derive the notation in the 
second integral from the notation in (1)?**

**Can I calculate the exemple using $\mathbf{r}(t)$ in cartesian coordinates?**

Comment: Very briefly, $\rho$ is the parameter. Usually you can use coordinates as parameters.

Answer (score 1):

That is exactly what you did here. You'r parametrization is - 
$$\vec{r} = (t,\phi_a,z_a),\;t\in[\rho_a,\rho_ b]$$
so - $$\vec{r}'=(1,0,0)$$
since $\phi_a=\phi_b, z_a=z_b$.

Comment: Thanks! I edited my post, I missed one thing. In my formula, $\mathbf{r}(t)$ is cartesian coordinates, i.e. $\mathbf{r}(t)=x(t)\mathbf{\hat i}+y(t)\mathbf{\hat j}+z(t)\mathbf{\hat k}$. Can I calculate the exemple using cartesian coordinates? Before electromagnetism I have only used [this approach](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/LineIntegralsVectorFields.aspx).

Comment: Your first formula works for any set of coordinates, it does not require the cartesian coordinates specifically.
If you want to calculate your example in cartesian coordinates you first have to change variables and then calculate the integral.